# How to configure Chrome's Java plugin so it uses an existing JDK in the machine

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins

When installing JDK in my machines (Windows 7), I do the following.

1. install latest 1.7 JDK with the Oracle installer (just the JDK, no [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment))
2. copy the install folder, to the place I really want, remove samples, etc.
3. uninstall Java
4. set %JAVA_HOME%, add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to %Path%

Then I synchronise that folder in all my machines so I keep it updated (with unlimited cryptography stuff, [jssecacerts](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/05/03/java_security.html?page=4), `java.policy`, endorsed libraries, etc).

**BUT** this has one big caveat, when Chrome needs to use load a page that uses Java, it thinks Java is not installed and wants to install it. I don't want to install it as it would mess with my 'hand-installed' JDK.

So is there a way to configure Chrome so it uses the JDK in my disk?
I have both JDK 32-bit and JDK 64-bit, so that is not a problem (I guess I would need to use the 32-bit one with Chrome).

I found a question in the Chrome project, *[How do I have the Chrome Java plugin reference an existing JDK without reinstalling Java?](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1187cd3f6c980910&hl=en)*, but no replies so far...

UPDATE: for Ubuntu, see Kalyan's answer

UPDATE: I still continue to use this approach successfully, last time with 1.7.0_21 on win7

UPDATE for 1.7.45: the path in the windows registry now is [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins]

Comment: Using Win7, Java 1.7.0_21, none of these answers works.  Chrome refuses to use my latest JDK/JRE.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Apparently, Chrome addresses a key in Windows registry when it looks for a Java Environment. Since the plugin installs the JRE, this key is set to a JRE path and therefore needs to be edited if you want Chrome to work with the JDK.

1. Run the plugin installer anyways.
2. Start -> Run (<kbd>Winkey+R</kbd>) and then type in `regedit` to edit the registry.
3. Find **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin**.
4. Export it as a reg file to say, your desktop (right-click and select **Export**).
5. Uninstall the JRE (Control Panel -> Add or Remove Programs). This should delete the key above, explaining the need to export it in the first place.
6. Open the reg file exported to your desktop with a text editor (such as Notepad++).
7. Edit "Path" so that it matches the corresponding dll inside your JDK installation:

   ```
   REGEDIT 4

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin]
   "Description"="Oracle® Next Generation Java™ Plug-In"
   "GeckoVersion"="1.9"

   "Path"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\jre\bin\new_plugin\npjp2.dll"

   "ProductName"="Oracle® Java™ Plug-In"
   "Vendor"="Oracle Corp."
   "Version"="160_29"
   ```
8. Save file.
9. Double click modified reg file to add keys to your registry.

The `REGEDIT 4` prefix at the top of the file might only be required for Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: To me it was sufficient to go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=10.3.1` and edit the `path` REG_SZ to new path. Then refreshed the chrome, remarkably not needed to restart chrome.

Comment: Works for me too, just changed path at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,ver‌​sion=x.x.x as Ciantic

Comment: You can omit Wow6432Node from your Registry path if you are using a Windows 7 32-bit environment. I found two DLLs referencing a different location. I did a find in Windows for the desired path and pasted this into the Registry.

Comment: There's nothing in Wow6432 for me (windows xp 32 bit)  see HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@java.com instead

Comment: The answer to this question changed on April 14, 2015, when Google updated Chrome to no longer allow NPAPI plugins such as Java.  See my answer below for workarounds.

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu, You can follow these steps to resolve the issue:

1. Create a directory named *plugins* inside `$HOME/.mozilla`, if it doesn't exist already
2. Create a symlink to *libnpjp2.so* inside this directory using this command:

   ```
   ln -s $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so $MOZILLA_HOME/plugins
   ```

   -**or**-

   ```
   ln -s $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so $MOZILLA_HOME/plugins
   ```

   depending on whether you're using a 32 or 64 bit JVM installation. Moreover, $JAVA_HOME is the location of your JVM installation.

More detailed instructions can be found [here](http://technonstop.com/install-java-plugin-ubuntu-linux).

Comment: Question is about Chrome, not Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

I use Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and have both the 32-bit and 64-bit Java 7u9 jre's installed.  Chrome refused to work until I deleted the following registry key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/MozillaPlugins/@java.com/DTPlugin,version=10.9.2
```

Then I refreshed Chrome and the Applet loaded with a Warning that the plugin was out of date.  I seleted "Run this time" and everything worked as expected.

There are two bugs related to this: [7118859](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7118859) & [7133818](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7133818)

Answer (score 5):

I came across a similar issue but instead of changing the regedit I decided to change the Chrome settings

Try the following steps

1. In the chrome browser type: `chrome://plugins/`
2. Click on `+ Details` (top right corner) to expand all the plugin details.
3. Find `Java` and click on `Disable` for the path(s) that you don't want to be used.

You might have to restart the browser to see the changes.  This also assumes that the Java that you have enabled is the latest Java.

Hope this helps

Comment: When you can see java under plugins then Java is being detected but the question here is that java is not being recognized by chrome and it is asking to install it again?

Answer (score 1):

I looked around for a solution to this for a while.
It appears that the JDK doesn't have the Mozilla plugins (which is what Chrome uses) in it's installation. It is only in the JRE installation. There are a couple of DLLs that make up the plugin and they all start with np*

Comment: But JDK always installs JRE. I see pluging directory in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\plugin2\`

Comment: Which plugin in JRE is mozilla plugin and also used by chrome?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 64-bit, I added the registry entry using the following script:

```
@echo off
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin" /v "Description" /t REG_SZ /d "Oracle Next Generation Java Plug-In"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin" /v "GeckoVersion" /t REG_SZ /d "1.9"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin" /v "Path" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Oracle\jdev11123\jdk160_24\jre\bin\new_plugin\npjp2.dll"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin" /v "ProductName" /t REG_SZ /d "Oracle Java Plug-In"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin" /v "Vendor" /t REG_SZ /d "Oracle Corp."
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin" /v "Version" /t REG_SZ /d "10.3.1"
```

Note that you will have to change the `Path`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Version 42, released April 14, 2015, Chrome blocks all NPAPI plugins, including Java.  Until September 2015 there will be a way around this, by going to `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` and clicking on `Enable`.  After that, you will have to use the [IE tab extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd) to run the Direct-X version of the Java plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit and couldn't understand if I can manually enable JRE8 64 bit for Chrome. Turned out that my problem was that Java plugin DLL is 64 bit which wouldn't work in 32 bit Chrome. Therefore you need to install x86 version of JRE. Below are Windows registry settings you need to create

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2]
"Description"="Oracle® Next Generation Java™ Plug-In"
"GeckoVersion"="1.9"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre8\\bin\\plugin2\\npjp2.dll"
"ProductName"="Oracle® Java™ Plug-In"
"Vendor"="Oracle Corp."
"Version"="1.8.0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.8.0]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.1]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.1]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.2]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.1.3]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.2]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.2.1]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.3]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.3.1]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.4]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.1]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.5]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.6]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.7]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-applet;version=1.8]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-vm]
"Description"="Java™ Virtual Machine"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin,version=11.0.2\MimeTypes\application/x-java-vm-npruntime]
"Description"="Java™ Applet"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin]
"Description"="Oracle® Next Generation Java™ Plug-In"
"GeckoVersion"="1.9"
"ProductName"="Oracle® Java™ Plug-In"
"Vendor"="Oracle Corp."
"Version"="160_29"
"Path"="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre8\\bin\\plugin2\\npjp2.dll"
```