# Google chrome custom JRE/JDK/plugin

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, java

I am using JDK 1.5 on my system as a java developer. But chrome needs 1.6 or later. So, I install the latest JDK for chrome but I have the system variable path pointing to the jdk1.5. So, chrome does not work with it. I need the JDK pointing to 1.5 in the system path for my regular development so can't change it.

Is there any way I can specify the JDK or JRE to be used by chrome separately?

Comment: Chrome certainly only needs a JRE, not a JDK.

Comment: thats not helpful at all. and i know that already

Comment: Care to explain what a *system variable path* is?

Comment: I think [this][1] is what you are looking for?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962048/how-to-configure-chromes-java-plugin-so-it-uses-an-existing-jdk-in-the-machine