# Java version with IE and Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, java

I have the following issue:
I have two OS installed (XP and W7 32bit), because I have to apps, one works with jre-6u23, another one with jre-7u7, on these two OS I have installed two versions of Java (`jre-6u23` and `jre-7u7`)

What I am trying to do is :

- Force IE to use the `jre-6u2`
- Force Chrome to use the `jre-7u7`

below is what I've tried:

- To change the value of UseJava2IExplorer on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in`
- To set the default java version via **Control Pannel**

Thank you in advance
Emiliano

Comment: Forcing your web browsers to use out-of-date versions of Java is crazy.  Upgrade to the latest ... if you value your system security.

Comment: I have to apps, one works with jre-6u23, another one with jre-7u7

Comment: @Gnu_nix and the one that works on jre-6u23 does _not_ work on jre-7u7?

Comment: nope, these two apps work only with these specific versions (I know it sounds crazy, but that is how it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the solution I've found:

1) I've installed **chromeinstall-7u21.exe**

2) **Copied** the **jre7** folder to **C:**

3) **Uninstalled** jre-7u21

4) Modifiy the **MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin** registry key in order to point Chrome to use the folder store in **C:** (see [How to configure Chrome's Java plugin so it uses an existing JDK in the machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962048/how-to-configure-chromes-java-plugin-so-it-uses-an-existing-jdk-in-the-machine))

Thx for your help anyway ;D