# How to change Chrome's JRE version?

Tags: java, google-chrome

Well let's suppose I have 3 JDK needed for development in my local machine.

I am having some Java issues when trying to pay some bill on my Internet Banking, only in Chrome.

The `chrome://plugins/` shows this:

```
Java(TM) (2 files) - Versão: 10.45.2.18
NPRuntime Script Plug-in Library for Java(TM) Deploy
```

So, how can I change the version of my java used by my Chrome?

My JAVA_HOME is `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"`

Thank you guys!

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962048/how-to-configure-chromes-java-plugin-so-it-uses-an-existing-jdk-in-the-machine

Comment: Very good. But my WOW6432Node regedit folder is empty. I found the plugin in other folder: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\@java.com/JavaPlugin`

Thank you @EvertonAgner