# I want to force an Applet to only use Java 1.6 (Java 6)

Tags: java, applet, version

I have inherited support for an old Java Applet (written circa 2010) in Java 6, (1.6) to support. I have even inherited support for a couple of Java 3 applets.

The Java 3 works as the following code surrounds the applet

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
WIDTH = 100% HEIGHT = 100% ALIGN = "baseline"  
codebase="http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.3/jinstall-13-win32.cab#Version=1,3,0,0">

<PARAM NAME = CODE VALUE = "ODBSServerGUI\OLIVE.class" >
<PARAM NAME = ARCHIVE VALUE = "olive.jar" >

<PARAM NAME="type" VALUE="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.3.0_02">
<PARAM NAME="scriptable" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME = "port" VALUE ="20285">
<PARAM NAME = "host" VALUE ="MOGH">
</OBJECT>
```

I need something similar for my Java 6 application, as the Java 6 application does not run with Java 7 or 8. I can not just simply re-compile it, as some of the original source code is missing, and decompiling and re-compiling is a very involved process.
The Java 6 application currently ran like this, but I now need to force the version and possibly download a "temporary" copy of the code into peoples' browsers.

```
<object classid="clsid:8AD9C840-044E-11D1-B3E9-00805F499D93"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        align= "baseline">
    <param name="code" value="SiteCommApplet.TestTool.class" >
    <param name="archive" value="/RMCommandCentre/dist/OTTApp.jar">
    <param name="username" value="<?php echo $userdetails['User']['name'];?>">
    <param name="connid" value="<?php echo $dbconnection['Dbconnection']['id'];?>">   
</object>
```

Can somebody please help me.
(I apologise in advance that I am having problems with the formatting.)

I have just tried the following, but with no luck

```
<object classid="clsid: CAFEEFAC-0016-0025-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        align= "baseline" codebase="http://java.sun.com/update/1.6.0/jinstall-6u25-windows-i586.cab#Version=1,6,25,0">
    <param name="code" value="SiteCommApplet.TestTool.class" >
    <param name="archive" value="/RMCommandCentre/dist/OTTApp.jar">
    <PARAM NAME="type" VALUE="application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.6.0">
    <param name="username" value="<?php echo $userdetails['User']['name'];?>">
    <param name="connid" value="<?php echo $dbconnection['Dbconnection']['id'];?>">   
</object>
```

I got that from information on the page https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8161117?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel but the link appears to be broken.

Comment: What environtment did you use to run this? Applets have been removed from the java runtime as well as from browsers.

Comment: Have you tried to add similar `codebase` attributes and param `type` tags to the latter `object` tag?

Comment: I would like to do that, but I don't know what the codebase should read nor the type line. That would be my ideal solution. The Java 1.3 ones work fine in Edge in IE mode.

Answer (score 0):

I do not envy you for having simply inherited these applets. Even if you had a chance of getting Java 6 running somewhere today, you would hardly find support in case of problems. And today's browsers may even stop supporting Java Applets altogether (e.g. see [How to launch an applet using chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843774/how-to-launch-an-applet-using-chrome))

Not having the full source code is adding yet another layer of complexity and risk.

Thus you might want to find completely other solutions. You could run everything on the client using [Webstart](https://openwebstart.com/). Or you could run everything on the server using [WebSwing](https://www.webswing.org/). Or anything inbetween using a website with GWT or React JS or Angular or whatnot. But staying on Applets is no more state of the art.

Comment: Whatever is chosen, it needs to keep a persistent TCP/IP connection to a server, through its various stages, as the applet's user is using it to talk to (configure and query) telemetry units eventually via PSTN dial up connections and modems.

Comment: If you are talking about remote administration via Internet, definitely do not use technology that was deprecated for security issues.

Comment: It is on our company Intranet. It provides a GUI option for people who can not remember the commands to type in at a prompt on our server. This GUI takes the commands from drop-down menus but sends the commands to the server (which sends them onwards).